# Spring injecting singleton bean into prototype bean causing singleton re-creation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I currently have a simple `singleton` bean as a pojo, which i'm injecting into a worker thread, which is defined with `@scope("prototype")`.

I'm finding that rather the `singleton` bean being correctly injected into the prototype,the `singleton` is being re-initialised and all the values are returning `null`.

Here's the code to inject the `singleton`:

```
@Component("filterWorkerPaired")
@Scope("prototype")
public class FilteringWorkerPaired implements FilteringWorker {


private RangeFilteringParams rangeFilteringParams;


@Inject
@Named("rangeFilteringParams")
public void setRangeFilteringParams(RangeFilteringParams rangeFilteringParams) {
    this.rangeFilteringParams = rangeFilteringParams;
}
```

The Pojo:

```
@Component("rangeFilteringParams")
public class RangeFilteringParams {

private Footprint footprint;
private SpanLength spanLength;
private WindowLength windowLength;
private boolean isPaired;
private List<MappingStrandSE> mappingStrandsSE;
private List<MappingTypeSE> mappingTypesSE;
private List<MappingStrandPE> mappingStrandsPE;
private List<MappingTypePE> mappingTypesPE;
private String suffix;
private boolean isLastStream = false; //default

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    System.out.println("init filtering ");
}

@PreDestroy
public void destory(){
    System.out.println("destoryed");
}

public boolean isLastStream() {
    return isLastStream;
}

public void setLastStream(boolean lastStream) {
    isLastStream = lastStream;
}

public Footprint getFootprint() {
    return footprint;
}

public void setFootprint(Footprint footprint) {
    this.footprint = footprint;
}

public String getSuffix() {
    return suffix;
}

public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
    this.suffix = suffix;
}

public SpanLength getSpanLength() {
    return spanLength;
}

public void setSpanLength(SpanLength spanLength) {
    this.spanLength = spanLength;
}

public WindowLength getWindowLength() {
    return windowLength;
}

public void setWindowLength(WindowLength windowLength) {
    this.windowLength = windowLength;
}

public boolean isPaired() {
    return isPaired;
}

public void setPaired(boolean paired) {
    isPaired = paired;
}

public List<MappingStrandSE> getMappingStrandsSE() {
    return mappingStrandsSE;
}

public void setMappingStrandsSE(List<MappingStrandSE> mappingStrandsSE) {
    this.mappingStrandsSE = mappingStrandsSE;
}

public List<MappingTypeSE> getMappingTypesSE() {
    return mappingTypesSE;
}

public void setMappingTypesSE(List<MappingTypeSE> mappingTypesSE) {
    this.mappingTypesSE = mappingTypesSE;
}

public List<MappingStrandPE> getMappingStrandsPE() {
    return mappingStrandsPE;
}

public void setMappingStrandsPE(List<MappingStrandPE> mappingStrandsPE) {
    this.mappingStrandsPE = mappingStrandsPE;
}

public List<MappingTypePE> getMappingTypesPE() {
    return mappingTypesPE;
}

public void setMappingTypesPE(List<MappingTypePE> mappingTypesPE) {
    this.mappingTypesPE = mappingTypesPE;
}
```

}

I know that the `RangeFileringParams` bean is being recreated, as the ID changes in the debugger, and `init filtering` is printed to the console.

Is there something wrong with injecting a singleton into a prototype in this way?

thanks.

Comment: Can you see the PostConstruct method executing multiple times?

Comment: Just the once, but interestingly, I don't see the PreDestroy before the PostConstruct.

Comment: Just a guess - although the default scope is singleton try explicitly marking `RangeFilteringParams` scope as singleton.

Comment: I think you would only see PreDestroy when you are closing the context

Comment: explicitly marking the scope doesn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: I may missing something. So you create the RangeFilteringParams as an empty bean and then your prototype beans are updating the fields?

Comment: The params bean is instantiated and set at an earlier stage, and holds the users requests for how they'd like to filter the specific data. The worker then takes the params, and a chunk of the data and filters.

Comment: That's the problem. Show us the code you used to initialize the bean

Comment: But how is it "instantiated" you are using the @Component annotation so Spring will do the job for you. but you have to set the data for yourself. Are you getting the bean from the context and then update the data?

Comment: Solved the issue, thanks anyway. The beans were being reset in another part of the code, and not re instantiated correctly until the hit the filtering. doh..

Answer (score 1):

As you said it is solved but anyways. If you are creating a bean with initial state i would recommend using configuration instead of just the @Component annotation and then you can create the bean and initialize the fields in one place.
For example:

```
@Configuration
public class RangeFilteringParamsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RangeFilteringParams rangeFilteringParams() {
        RangeFilteringParams params = new RangeFilteringParams();
        //set the fields here...
        return params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not auto-wired the singleton bean if you are just creating the prototype bean with the new operator.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ExamplePType implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    private transient Cache cache
}
```

Below some won't give the auto-wired bean which is injected in ExamplePType class.

```
  ExamplePType obj = new ExamplePType ();
```

Create object using Application Context to aware the injected bean to persist the auto-wired bean.

```
@Component
public class Factory implements ApplicationContextAware {   
    private ApplicationContext ctx;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = ctx;

    }       
    public String run() {               
        ExamplePType obj = ctx.getBean(ExamplePType.class);        
    }   
}
```